# How to update Python which download from official website?

Tags: macos, python, development, developer-program

I'm mac user, and I downloaded Python from the offcial website. What if I want to update Python, what should I do? I also installed the Java JDK from offcial website, both of them are .pkg, can someone tell me how to update them if they can be updated?

Comment: Please add your system version `sw_vers` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed you can type in the terminal:

```
brew install python3
```

Otherwise you can just download it again from [the website](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) and install it.

If you don't know which version of python you have installed type `python --version` or `python3 --version`. Similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687357/updating-python-on-mac) have been answered on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip) and other [websites](https://osxtips.net/how-to-update-python-on-mac/).